# sending email by pressing button (Swift4)

Tags: ios, email, server, swift4, server-side

I trying to follow this YouTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkpLqNN8xtU. This youtube video lets the user send data via email. By just clicking the button. The problem I am not getting the email in my inbox. I am noticing some information in my log file. The problem is that by hitting the button I am not getting a email. In the flog file I took out my IP address.

```
 @IBAction func sendemail() {
    let smtpSession = MCOSMTPSession()
    //
    smtpSession.hostname = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpSession.username = "charlesxavier1221@gmail.com"
    smtpSession.password = "fakepassword1234"
    smtpSession.port = 465
    smtpSession.authType = MCOAuthType.saslPlain
    smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionType.TLS
    smtpSession.connectionLogger = {(connectionID, type, data) in
        if data != nil {
            if let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
                NSLog("Connectionlogger: \(string)")
            }
        }
    }
    let builder = MCOMessageBuilder()
    builder.header.to = [MCOAddress(displayName: "Charles", mailbox: "bincolawnmowing@gmail.com")]
    builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: "Xavier", mailbox: "bincolawnmowing@gmail.com")
    builder.header.subject = "Test Email"
    builder.htmlBody="<p>Thank you for watching</p>"


    let rfc822Data = builder.data()
    let sendOperation = smtpSession.sendOperation(with: rfc822Data)
    sendOperation?.start { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("Error sending email: \(error)")


        } else {
            NSLog("Successfully sent email!")


        }
    }
}
```

LOG FILE

```
2018-10-07 20:16:25.866786-0400 createForm[3497:330541] 
 Connectionlogger: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP s5sm2700758otc.40 - gsmtp

   2018-10-07 20:16:25.875403-0400 createForm[3497:330541] 
Connectionlogger: EHLO Johns-MacBook-Pro.local

   2018-10-07 20:16:25.943218-0400 createForm[3497:330541] 
  Connectionlogger: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [#myIPAddress]

    250-SIZE 35882577
    250-8BITMIME
   250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
     250-PIPELINING
    250-CHUNKING
     250 SMTPUTF8

       2018-10-07 20:16:25.943610-0400 createForm[3497:330541] 
        Connectionlogger: AUTH PLAIN  
        Y2hhcmxlc3hhdmllcjEy
         MjFAZ21haWwuY29tAGNoYXJsZXN
         4YXZpZXIxMjIxQGdtYWlsLmNvb
        QBmYWtlcGFzc3dvcmQxMjM0

         2018-10-07 20:16:26.064998-0400 createForm[3497:330541] Connectionlogger:         
        535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
         535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 
         s5sm2700758otc.40 - gsmtp

       2018-10-07 20:16:26.067524-0400 createForm[3497:326547] Error sending email: Optional(Error Domain=MCOErrorDomain Code=5 "Unable to authenticate with the current session's credentials." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to authenticate with the current session's credentials.})
```

Comment: You can clearly see from the log that your username and/or password are incorrect

Comment: But to what? For this To work I have to provide my gmail username and password. What If I am not using gmail.

Comment: Yes, you need to provide a valid username and password. You wouldn't expect Google to let anybody send email through their servers; they would get blocked by spam lists for running an open relay.

Comment: What I am confused about is the difference between smtpSession.hostname = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpSession.username = "charlesxavier1221@gmail.com"
    smtpSession.password = "fakepassword1234" and  let builder = MCOMessageBuilder()
    builder.header.to = [MCOAddress(displayName: "Charles", mailbox: "bincolawnmowing@gmail.com")]
    builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: "Xavier", mailbox: "bincolawnmowing@gmail.com")
    builder.header.subject = "Test Email"
    builder.htmlBody="<p>Thank you for watching</p>"

Which one is where I put the outgoing email.

Comment: The email will come from the sender associated with the mailbox you specify, but the username/password you provide must have authorisation to send email from that mailbox.

Comment: I get what your saying that in smtpSession I should put in my real email and password but what do I do about hostname and port I dont know that .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181517/discussion-between-paulw11-and-sam-burns).